# Change Span CSS Class OnClick

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

I have a Span tag like so

```
<span id="SpanHeader" class="CourseHeader"><a class="SubCourses" href="#" ><strong>@course.CourseTitle</strong></a></span>
```

The Span is styled by a CSS class called CourseHeader. When the user clicks the hyperlink within the Span I would like the Span CSS class to toggle with another CSS class.

I have the following CSS elements

```
/********* Course Collaspable Headings ******/
.CourseHeader
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 600px; 
    padding: 4px; 
    color: Black;
}

.CourseHeader.Black
{
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And the following JQuery code to try and make the Span change style once the hyperlink is clicked

```
$("a.SubCourses").click(onSubCourses);

function onSubCourses() {

    $(".SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");

}
```

I've tried looking at how others have achieved this, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/r5WWQ/) however I can't get it working myself.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be,  You have used `id` selector in  HTML `<span id="SpanHeader" class="CourseHeader">`

```
$("#SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");
```

instead of

```
 $(".SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can simplify the function if you don't need to reuse the function, then it's an ID not a class so it should be `#SpanHeader`

```
$("a.SubCourses").click(function() {

    $("#SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've just have a minor mistake in the css selector for the id

```
$("#SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");
```

I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26dUe/

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting class .SpannerHeader element which is not exist in your DOM. Instead you should select by ID.

Like following:

```
$("a.SubCourses").click(onSubCourses);

function onSubCourses(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");
}
```

**[Here is working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/WjhAM/)**

Answer (score 1):

SpanHeader is a class. It is Id so, just change

```
$("a.SubCourses").click(onSubCourses);

     function onSubCourses() {

    $("#SpanHeader").toggleClass("Black");

}
```